# multiple images in a picturebox (with alpha channel)

Tags: c#, picturebox, alpha

I'm designing a program that will have a photoshop-like layer interface.
I want to have multiple images in a picturebox at the **same time**, some will be higher
some will be lower, every single one of them(the images) wiil have a alpha channel.
the final image in the picturebox will be the combine Image of all of them with the alpha channel.

is it possible to do so like that?

please note that after loading the images, the user can change properties in every added picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple images in a Windows Forms PictureBox, no.

You can create a single image from multiple images and blend them in various ways, then show that image in a PictureBox.

Or, you could overlay multiple picture boxes, using different opacity set on the PictureBox control.